# Convert 8-bit grayscale image to 7-bit grayscale image

Tags: image, matlab, grayscale

I want to convert my original 8-bit depth gray scale image to a 7-bit depth gray scale image (pixel values should be in the range `[0 127]`.

I use the below syntax, however pixels with value equal to `255` will change to `128` (it seems they are rounded after division, i.e. `127.5` changes to `128`). How can I resolve this issue and keep my pixel values in the range `[0 127]` after division?

```
RGB = imread('camera_man128x128.png')% read 8-bit image
RGB = RGB*0.5; %change pixel value to be in range to 0~127
               %however pixels with value 255 change to 128.
```

Comment: You cannot have 7-bit data type in MATLAB. You can rescale your data to 0-127 integers though. Do you want that?

Comment: @SardarUsama yes, that't right. I want to store values in `unit8` but only I want to change data scale from 0~127.

Comment: Floor your data, or divide by the max in your data after division and the multiply by 127

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do it is to use [`bitshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html):

```
RGB = bitshift(RGB, -1);
```

This shifts the bit pattern of each `uint8` value one to the right, equivalent to multiplication by 2<sup>-1</sup> (i.e. division by 2), such that `255` will become `127`.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your data type to [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) and then multiply with 0.5. Use [`floor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) to round towards negative infinity and then convert back to [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html).

```
RGB = uint8(floor(double(RGB)*0.5));
```